# FragmentManager findFragmentById return null

Tags: android, android-fragments

The code of activity_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

The code of CrimeListActivity.java

```
package com.sinory.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;

public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("CrimeListActivity", "create");
    }

}
```

The code of SingleFragmentActivity.java

```
package com.sinory.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (null == fragment) {
            fragment = new CrimeListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Just started to learn Android. Why Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer) is null? Please help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you don't need to check if the fragment is null because when an activity destroys all the fragment will also be destroyed. So in activity onCreate there will be no fragment and you need to add it each time the activity recreates. 

Second don't use findFragmentById. You only use this method when you define your fragment inside your xml file. Now that you dynamically adding your fragment you need to specify a string tag and then use that tag to find the fragment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,"TagName").commit();
}
```

if you need to find your fragment simply use this code

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("TagName");
```

**Update on January 9, 2019**

As of 2018, you can simply use Google Navigation library to navigate between the pages (fragments) in the app. It will handle all the transactions and makes it a lot easier and cleaner to do the navigation. check it out here 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

Comment: "You only use this method when you define your fragment inside your xml file." That's not quite true. You can add fragment to specified ViewGroup in activity.xml: getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.someFrameLayoutForExample, new MainFragment())
                    .commit(); Then retrieve it getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.someFrameLayoutForExample); Key point here and using findFragmentByTag() is that before finding you must add first. No matter how it will be done - via xml or code.

Answer (score 2):

Sinory, The story is much Deeper than the accepted and 11 upvoted answers!

Let me begin by saying: All Android developer must deeply understand that we Don't own the Android Components. That means we Don't create them, nor destroy them. This is all done by Android System. And the only thing we can do is on the callbacks that we get. These are the hooks where we can run our code. You might be thinking I am getting thrown off the topic but soon you will understand why I started with this para.

Problems in the accepted Answer: "it will always be null" NO, Absolutely Wrong.

Now lets understand why you wrote this code and what went wrong in your understanding(and not just in your code):
You got callback onCreate(), and you thought oh! previously I added a fragment. maybe first time it will be null, and once added next time I will get the instance in the FragmentManager! *The reason you thought like that is because you missed to understand WHO KILLED THE ACTIVITY!!*

You know, Had Android destroyed your activity, on recreation you would have found your Fragment! and In-fact upon trying to re-adding, you would have crashed your code. But keep in mind these are all new instances, just mimicking the previous killed objects so that user on the UI do not get confuse. how this happened? Read Activity and Fragment onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState for Activity and onViewStateRestored for fragment methods.

So I really goest back to WHO KIILED THE INSTACE!

Lets see how can the activity be killed

1. By User: By pressing back button, the activity pops out of the back stack of task, and hence the object is destroy. Now the user Intended to destroy So the story ends here. Upon restarting the activity everything will start brand new! without any trace of previous actions being performed on the previous instance. And it makes sense right? because you wanted to get out the screen, so why would you expect the same scene being set for you again! makes sense?
2. By Android: This happens for many reasons, read documents about it. In short, when you click on home button and your activity is not on the surface for user to interact, and Android have difficulty finding memory for more important work that user maybe doing right now. Then It starts killing the backgrounders. And there get your activity killed!  .... But hey, now you as a user when you return to that killed activity again, This time you would expect this activity to be exactly how you left it right!!. But the Object is killed by Android.

Object recreation by Android: So now, when Android killed it, its responsible enough to do smart things and try to present it back to user as he left it, but again! Android needs your help as developer to write code at right callback hooks etc to accomplish the task. So what it does is:

1. Before killing the instance, it saves the state of that Activity instance in a bundle, giving the developer also a chance to save their data if any they need to. by callbacks onSaveInstanceState.
2. New Activity instance is created.
3. So the new fragment manager is also created. 
   Now both of these instances are provided with the previous state so that they can copy the same content to mimic perfectly like nothing happened.

**that is where you new fragmentManager instance can still find the fragment in this case and your fragment will be not null!!! Hurray**

So yes its possible to get a non null fragment with your code, but the correct way to write this code is to Identify who killed the instance. And one way is to check if savedInstanceBundle is null or not. If null, means user killed the instance, or its the first instance ever!

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Activity was killed by system.
        // Activity state was saved before killing the previous instance,
        // Doing so it also saved all the fragments in the fragmentManager!.
        // NOTE: It won't save the transaction history! so don't expect that 
        // any fragment that was added, and then later in the flow removed will
        // be saved and later found. ok. keep that in mind very important.


        // So when new Activity is created, new FragmentManager is also created, and it also restores its state with the previous snapshot. i.e bundle. by creating a new instance of fragment and adding to itself.
```

and hence you find your fragment. But hey the newly found fragment is a NEW INSTANCE. and not the previous ones. Remember everybody is trying to MIMICK.

```
        testFragment = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    } else {
        // User killed, or its the first time ever this activity is created. So           simply create one instance of fragment and add.
        testFragment = new TestFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, testFragment).commitNow();
    }
```

I am sure if you read, understand and reason enough. It will help building your understanding about Android, and benefit in long run.

Answer (score 1):

It will be null when there is no fragment with that id. That's normal flow. However a better approach is to use findFragmentByTag instead. Since you set the tags to anything when you create fragments and add/replace them on the manager, its easy to find and track them by tags.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I was calling the "findFragmentById()" method a little bit after adding the fragment and so the transaction wasn't completed.

So immediately before calling this method I called "excutePedingTransactions()"
and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK it's null. It tells you that the fragment wasn't created yet. that is why a few lines afterwards you are creating it.

The `onCreate` method can be called when the activity is restarted/recreated, and in this case, the Fragments that use to exist will still exist and then the reference will be not null.

Comment: When the program starts will call `onCreate`,but I write the code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment)` why it still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this as suggested, and I am still getting a null return value.

```
   FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTran = fragMan.beginTransaction();

        ControlsFragment ctrlFrag = new ControlsFragment();

        fragTran.add(R.id.fragment_container, ctrlFrag, "ctrl");
        fragTran.commit(); // commit additions

        FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment test = fm.findFragmentByTag("ctrl");
        System.out.println(test);
        Spinner spin1 = (Spinner)test.getView().findViewById(R.id.rythmspinner2);
    System.out.println(spin1);
        if (spin1 != null) spin1.setSelection(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line of code right before the line where I was calling `findFragmentById` and getting a null value, to give me the list of fragments that existed there:

```
List<Fragment> listFrags = getActiveFragments();
```

Then, I added a breakpoint there by tapping the column to the left. Then, I ran the app in debug mode. I looked at `listFrags` in the debugger when I hit that breakpoint and saw my desired fragment in the list. I looked for the following two values:

- `mTag` (this is returned by `findFragmentByTag`)
- `mFragmentId` (this is returned by `findFragmentById`)

By inspecting this way, I learned I needed to use `findFragmentByTag` to get my desired fragment instead of `findFragmentById`. I hope this solution and/or these debug steps are helpful to one or more of you.