# How to call a Class(Tabfragment.java) to another Fragment(DeliveryTab.java?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I created a Tabs one for `Footer menu` and another for just a fragment class inside this i have `3 Tabs`.

I want to call `Footer menu` (Tabfragment.java)in another fragment(DeliveryTab.java).

I search it on google and revise the stackoverflow's question but none are helping me..

Here i post complete code.

**activity_deliverytab.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TabFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_delivery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/tabMedium" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/tabfragment"></include>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_delivery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `activity_delivery_tab.xml` here.

Comment: @EricB. i just update it please take a look

Comment: @EricB. should i post my tabfragment.xml too??

Comment: See my answer. I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: DeliveryTab fragment and Tabfragment are calling from same activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `Fragment` in your layout using the `fragment` tag. Like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".TabFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_delivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/tabMedium" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_delivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
<!-- Since you want it to be in the footer -->

  <fragment android:name="xyz.xyz.xyz.TabFragment"
            android:id="@+id/tabFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you change the `android:name="xyz.xyz.xyz.TabFragment"` with your class name?

Comment: yes.. and  i think it is working but when i select Delivery from navigation drawer it is displaying only the tab of Delivery.xml

Comment: and it is displaying the all data of tabfragment

Comment: What else do you want?

Comment: the Tabfragment is covering the full screen and there's no space for the Deliveryta.xml in layout

Comment: Then you should change the height of the TabFragment. Replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `fragment` tag with some fixed height in `dp`.

Comment: opposite of the Tabfragment.. it is displaying the DElivertab.xml data not the tabfragment.xml data only tabs are visible

Comment: wait i'll upload a image too so that u cm to know where's the problem is

Comment: i set height = 150dp of an include fragment

Comment: What do you actually want to happen? Can you draw something and show me?

Comment: have you seen my images?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130754/discussion-between-eric-b-and-sachin).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am not sure but you can try like this
inside DeliveryTab.java

```
 ParentActivity activity = (ParentActivity) getActivity();
(ParentActivity is name of your activity which calls both TabsFragment and DeliveryTab )
```

Now get TabsFragment from FrameLayout or fragment whatever you set your TabsFragment  like

```
((TabsFragment ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FragmentContainer))
```

How to add tag to Fragment see this -https://stackoverflow.com/a/23370128/4741746

Now you have TabsFragment  now get ViewPager

`mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getPosition);`